# HtmlElement.invoke(“click”) doesn't work

Tags: c#, forms, browser, onclick

I'm trying to create an application that can fill html form automatically using WebBrowser control(C#). There is a option list on the web page and I can get corresponding elements in the drop down box. But when I call the `invokemember("click")` methods, there is no responce.Below in the selection element of HTML

```html
<div>
class="ddlcont" style="display: block; width: 150px; top: 414px; left: 790.75px;">   
<a class="select" v="0" href="javascript:;">Not </a>
<a v="419000" href="javascript:;">insure</a></div>
```

Here is my codes,I find `ScrollIntoView` and `Focus` method is ok

```cs
HtmlElementCollection element_div=currentWindow.Frames[0].Document.GetElementsByTagName ("div");

foreach (HtmlElement item in element_div)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("classname") == "ddlcont" && item.Children.Count !=0)
    {
        item.Children[1].ScrollIntoView(true);
        item.Children[1].Focus();
        item.Children [1].SetAttribute("selected", "true");
        item.Children [1].InvokeMember("Click");                    
    }  
}
```

I am appreciate that if anyone can help me to solve the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may have pasted wrong, but in your example `div` doesn't have a `class`.
Look:

```
<div>
class="ddlcont" style="display: block; width: 150px; top: 414px; left: 790.75px;">
```

should be

```
<div
class="ddlcont" style="display: block; width: 150px; top: 414px; left: 790.75px;">
```

(no `>` on the first line)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead:

```
Button1.GetType().GetEvent("OnClick").GetRaiseMethod().Invoke(Button1, EventArgs.Empty);
```

You may need to tweak the syntax a little bit, but this should put you on the right path.